# SPFx React Webpart - Using PnPJs to add files to list field

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, spfx, react

I'm building an application using SPFx Webpart with React. On one of my components I have a form that the user can fill out. I'm using PnPjs to push the user's responses into my list field. Everything works as expected.

I was looking at how to add a file or attachment field type to a list. I saw I can do it in the powerapps. So now in my "Product" list I have a field called `attachments`. When I attach files to that field from SharePoint's backend and then make a call to the list using `PnPjs` the attachment field does not return information about the files. But rather a `boolean` with a true or false.

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Products").items.filter("Id eq '" + this.props.match.params.id + "'").top(1).get().then((items: any[]) => {
    console.log(items); 
}
```

So this works perfect. Now in my `items` console I get back `Attachments: true` or `Attachments: false`

I'm using `react-dropzone` to allow users to upload files. Using `PnPjs` how do I upload the files to that item?

Here is how I'm creating the item:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Requests").items.add({
    Title: this.state.SuggestedVendor,
    Client_x0020_Email: this.state.getEmail,
    Created: this.state.startDate,
    Attachments: //need help here
}
```

Here is my code for the dropdown files:

```
onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
   console.log(acceptedFiles);
   //Assuming this is where I do the logic
}

<Dropzone 
    onDrop={this.onDrop}
    multiple
    >
    {({getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive}) => (
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {isDragActive ? "Drop it like it's hot!" : 'Click me or drag a file to upload!'}
        </div>
    )}
</Dropzone>
```

And here is the response I get back from `console.log(acceptedFiles);`:

```
[File]
0: File {path: "John-Hancock-signature.png", name: "John-Hancock-signature.png", lastModified: 1590783703732, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 29 2020 13:21:43 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
length: 1
```

I found this documentation here on how to push the files : https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/

Answer (score 0):

Sample test script for your reference.

```
onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    //console.log(acceptedFiles);
    //just one file
    let file=acceptedFiles[0];
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("TestList").items.add({
      Title: "Upload Attachement"
    }).then(r => {
      // this will add an attachment to the item we just created to push t sharepoint list
      r.item.attachmentFiles.add(file.name, file).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
    })
  }
```

You could check the [guideline](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/attachments/) here also.

Comment: wow! thanks for your help. So this did in fact push the file name to a new item list. So this file upload field is part of the form. So I don't want to use the `.add` here I want to make this push in the `.add` function in my original post. Can you help me with that? is this what i use? `await item.attachmentFiles.add("file2.txt", "Here is my content");`

Comment: Because with the current code it just adds the name of whatever the file was.. it doesn't actually store it in the request or SharePoint